# How to show a full page width image above chapter title, and different image for each chapter?

Tags: graphics, header-footer

I'm trying to make the chapter header follow the style:
- Chapter tittle is on its own page. 
- There is an image with full page width above the title, and different image for each chapter. 
- Optional: the image have caption, and can be link to list of figures.

I'm not new to tex, but my knowledge is quite like a beginner. And I have no idea about which packages/commands to use for this task. Thanks for your help.

**Update**
Thanks @Bernard, with your help I could place the image at where I want. But there is a problem still not done: How can I change image per chapter?

**Update 2: The final solution**

I use a new command to define the image name, and renew it, which the name of image I want to use for new chapter. To make thing easier, I also create a new command to do all the work. Please see my code and the result below. Very much thanks to @Bernard for your time.

[image: The result I want]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lobstertwo}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit,newlinetospace]{titlesec}%

\newcommand{\chapterimage}{nothing}

\newcommand{\newchapter}[2]{
    \renewcommand{\chapterimage}{#2}
    \chapter{#1}
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\titleline[c]{\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth]{\chapterimage}}\vskip4ex\bfseries}%
{\LARGE\chaptername \thechapter}{4ex}%
{\lsstyle \Huge\filcenter{\itshape\LobsterTwo#1}}[\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage]%

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-\dimexpr0.75\baselineskip + 1in + \voffset + \topmargin + \headheight + \headsep}{6\baselineskip}

\begin{document}%

    \newchapter{This is a very long\\ chapter title, which take\\ lot of space in header}{header}%    
    \newchapter{This is the second chapter header}{mouse}%
    \newchapter{This chapter use a cat image as its header}{cat}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to make any sort of sensible answer, we need more information, in particular the document class you're using.  my first guess would be that you would need to redefine the title block and `\maketitle`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Are you thinking of setting it up so `\maketitle` can be issued for each chapter? I would have expected redefining `\chapter` to be a more obvious move but maybe using something like `titling` and having each `\chapter` create a new title page makes more sense?

Comment: @cfr -- oops!  i should have said to redefine `\chapter`.  `\maketitle` is just plain wrong.  sorry!

Comment: It would be preferable to post your final solution as an answer so that people can more easily identify it. (There's no problem with answering your own question although the site enforces some sort of minimum waiting period, I think, and then rather annoyingly asks you if you are sure you really wouldn't rather edit your question.)

Comment: Oh, I don't know that. I will do it the next time :). Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `titleline` command, from the `titlesec`package allows to include horizontal material in headers.

Note I used the `lobster2` font only to get something similar to your image. It has to be loaded *before* any other font loading, as it redefines the default roman family. Also  I supposed this page should be unnumbered.

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lobstertwo}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{graphicx} 

    \usepackage{microtype}

    \usepackage[svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[explicit,newlinetospace]{titlesec}%

    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\titleline{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{titleimage.jpg}}\vskip4ex\bfseries}%
    {\LARGE\chaptername \thechapter}{4ex}%
    {\lsstyle \Huge\filcenter{\itshape\LobsterTwo#1}}[\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage]%

    \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-\dimexpr0.75\baselineskip + 1in + \voffset + \topmargin + \headheight + \headsep}{6\baselineskip}

    \begin{document}%

    \chapter{This is a very long\\ chapter title, which take\\ lot of space in header}%

    Some text

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bernard for suggesting the `titleline`, I try it, with a little modification from your code: `\titleline[c]{\includegraphics[width=\pdfpagewidth]{header}}`. It's seem work, except one thing that I can move the image on the top of page (with no margin). And, this solution may not allow to change the image for different chapter. I going to define a custom command for this task.

Comment: Do you mean you want the image at the top of the physical page? For the image perchapter problem, I had forgotten that requirement. I'll try to find a solution.

Comment: Yes, I want the image on top of physical page.

Comment: Done. See my updated answer.

Comment: Fine! I perhaps would prefer redefining the value of `\chapterimage` just before calling an ordinary `\chapter` command, but that's mainly a matter of personal taste.